# Installing cm-unicode font family on miktex for use with xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, miktex, truetype

I've been trying to install the font family `cm-unicode` on my MikTeX distribution (Windows 10). I'm new to XeLaTeX, and can't seem to find proper documentation on the installation of entire TrueType font families... The [archive](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm-unicode) available on CTAN or SourceForge has many different `.ttf` files, and I don't know where to put them in my `texmf` tree.

I don't understand the `INSTALL` file of the archive, as it describes installation using XFree86 and GhostScript, both of which I don't know.

Could someone point me to a relevant *detailed* explanation of how to install a `.ttf` font family for XeLaTeX, and how to use it (I mean, what to pass as an argument to the `fontspec \setmainfont` command, being there are so many different `.ttf` files), or better, describe it here ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should much more simply use `MiKTeX Package Manager`, wait for the list of available packages to appear, select `cm-unicode`, right click on it and select `install`:

[image]